# Migrating C# to VB code, getting "Must implement xxx"

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am attempting to add a spellcheck control in my winforms application in VS 2012 (VB).  The project is here:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73802/NHunspell-Component-for-Visual-Studio#Spelling%20control

The test application is using C#, so I am trying to translate from C# to VB.  I am getting errors saying that I am not implementing various parts of the interface.  For example I'm I didn't implement Focus.  (see screenshot).  However these were not implemented in the c# testing application which I translated to VB.  So I am wondering if i am doing something wrong, do I need to change the interface somehow?

[image: Errors in Visual Studio]

[image: The C# testing application I am migrating from]

Comment: The screenshots don't really support what you're saying.. There's far more to the code files than we can see.. are you sure you haven't implemented them further down in the C# class? Also your VB `UnderlinedSections` property has infinite recursion as you aren't using the field

Comment: In C#, code from a base class can 'automatically' implement an interface through implicit interface implementation. VB.NET doesn't work like that. See the duplicate.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate because the problem is different.  There are items in the base class in c# that I don't want to implement (or would rather leave alone). The errors are arising from this fact.

Comment: `This is not an exact duplicate` It may not be **exactly** the same, but it seems to me to be 99% the same. If you can convince us otherwise then we can reopen the question. This will involve creating a [mcve] (in text, not screenshots). `There are items in the base class in c# that I don't want to implement` That is not an option in VB.NET. Read the duplicate again - it shows you options for how to proceed. If you aren't happy with those options, you will need to stick with C#. Also, when you comment be sure to @ me, or I won't know you commented @Rob.

Comment: Solved by creating a library project instead of a Winforms project from the project.   Then drag the DLL to your toolbar on your WinForms project.  Note for this one there are many ancillary DLLs needed.  Also the methods within the library must be public.